# Attempting to create a docReference using Angular firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What I am attempting to do is create a document Reference in my Firebase database that will return me an id and a doc Reference, so I can use that id to create a path for this object's image in my storage.

So according to the firebase [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) I should be able to do this:

```
var newPlantRef = db.collection(`users/${this.userId}/plants`).doc();
```

But that is returning this error:

```
AddPlantComponent.html:30 ERROR FirebaseError: Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined
```

So I found a work-around on [Github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/1974) that says I should do this:

```
const id = this.afs.createId();
const ref = this.afs.collection(`users/${this.userId}/plants`).doc(id);
```

But when I do this:

```
this.newPlantId = this.db.createId();
this.newPlantRef = this.db.collection(`users/${this.userId}/plants`).doc(this.newPlantId).ref;
this.newPlantRef.update({
      name: 'Test1',
      primaryImgURL: 'test1',
      addedDate: new Date()
    });
  }
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: [code=not-found]: No document to update: projects/plant-app-d9298/databases/(default)/documents/users/UoV0MXMfZGhMgmMJHpiMU41aLZG2/plants/LWmM79JotgDn20hPOcA1
FirebaseError: No document to update: projects/plant-app-d9298/databases/(default)/documents/users/UoV0MXMfZGhMgmMJHpiMU41aLZG2/plants/LWmM79JotgDn20hPOcA1
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there some other workaround where I can get the document id before I've done an add so my items and storage can reference that id?

Comment: That's because you have to call the `set` method instead of the `update` method since that particular document doesn't exist in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You can push the document to the collection first and then it will return the id of the document. Use that id in your file path to upload it to firestorage and then you can update the document with the url and path ref.

something like this

```
uploadFile(id) {
const file = event.target.files[0];

let filePath = '';
filePath = 'path' + id;

const ref = this.afs.ref(filePath);
const task = ref.put(file);

// observe percentage changes
this.uploadPercent = task.percentageChanges();
// get notified when the download URL is available
return task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  finalize(() => {
    this.downloadURL = ref.getDownloadURL()
  })
).toPromise();
}


saveData() {
  const collectionRef = this.afs.collection('your path');
  collectionRef.add(data).then((res) => {
  const docId = res.id;
  // then upload the file
  this.uploadFile(docId)
  .then(() => {
              // then update the document
              this.downloadURL.subscribe(imgUrl => {
              const imageUrl = imgUrl;
                // Then update the document with imageUrl using the docId

              });
            });

});
```

hope it helps